# A* and N-Puzzle optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a solver for the N-Puzzle (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle)

Right now I am using a unordered_map to store hash values of the puzzle board,
and manhattan distance as the heuristic for the algorithm, which is a plain DFS.

so I have

```
    auto pred = [](Node * lhs, Node * rhs){ return lhs->manhattanCost_ < rhs->manhattanCost_; };
    std::multiset<Node *, decltype(pred)> frontier(pred);
    std::vector<Node *> explored; // holds nodes we have already explored
    std::tr1::unordered_set<unsigned> frontierHashTable;
    std::tr1::unordered_set<unsigned> exploredHashTable;
```

This works great for n = 2 and 3.
However, its really hit and miss for n=4 and above. (stl unable to allocate memory for a new node)

I also suspect that I am getting hash collisions in the unordered_set

```
unsigned makeHash(const Node & pNode)
{
unsigned int b    = 378551;
unsigned int a    = 63689;
unsigned int hash = 0;

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < pNode.data_.size(); i++)
{
    hash = hash * a + pNode.data_[i];
    a    = a * b;
}

return hash;
}
```

16! = 2 × 10^13 (possible arrangements)

2^32 = 4 x 10^9 (possible hash values in a 32 bit hash)

My question is how can I optimize my code to solve for n=4 and n=5?
I know from here
http://kociemba.org/fifteen/fifteensolver.html

http://www.ic-net.or.jp/home/takaken/e/15pz/index.html

that n=4 is possible in less than a second on average.

edit:
The algorithm itself is here:

```
bool NPuzzle::aStarSearch()
 {
auto pred = [](Node * lhs, Node * rhs){ return lhs->manhattanCost_ < rhs->manhattanCost_; };
std::multiset<Node *, decltype(pred)> frontier(pred);
std::vector<Node *> explored; // holds nodes we have already explored
std::tr1::unordered_set<unsigned> frontierHashTable;
std::tr1::unordered_set<unsigned> exploredHashTable;

// if we are in the solved position in the first place, return true
if(initial_ == target_)
{
    current_ = initial_;
    return true;
}

frontier.insert(new Node(initial_)); // we are going to delete everything from the frontier later..

for(;;)
{
    if(frontier.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "depth first search " << "cant solve!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


    // remove a node from the frontier, and place it into the explored set
    Node * pLeaf = *frontier.begin();
    frontier.erase(frontier.begin());
    explored.push_back(pLeaf);

    // do the same for the hash table
    unsigned hashValue = makeHash(*pLeaf);
    frontierHashTable.erase(hashValue);
    exploredHashTable.insert(hashValue);

    std::vector<Node *> children = pLeaf->genChildren();
    for( auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); ++it)
    {
        unsigned childHash = makeHash(**it);
        if(inFrontierOrExplored(frontierHashTable, exploredHashTable, childHash))
        {
            delete *it;
        }
        else
        {
            if(**it == target_)
            {
                explored.push_back(*it);
                current_ = **it;

                // delete everything else in children
                for( auto it2 = ++it; it2 != children.end(); ++it2)
                    delete * it2;

                // delete everything in the frontier
                for( auto it = frontier.begin(); it != frontier.end(); ++it)
                    delete *it;

                // delete everything in explored
                explored_.swap(explored);
                for( auto it = explored.begin(); it != explored.end(); ++it)
                    delete *it;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                frontier.insert(*it);
                frontierHashTable.insert(childHash);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is using up all of your memory?

Comment: I don't expect you to have any trouble for upto n=4 since I've coded this before. I don't think its your hash function. You may be doing something wrong in the algorithm.. check to see if you are terminating properly.

Comment: Just a little side-note: You are using lambdas and `auto` variables and `decltype`, which shows you clearly have a pretty up to date C++11 compiler, but you still use `tr1`? Is your standard library not updated yet? Otherwise you can use `std::unordered_map` instead.

Comment: You certainly have a problem with the "hashing". You should not use surjective hashes to remember what you have explored already! If you have a clash, then you will miss an expansion and thus skip over a path with a solution. You should use either node data or a non-surjective mapping of it.

Comment: I am pretty sure The issue is with hash collisions now, this causes me to ignore nodes that I would otherwise go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework I will suggest some strategies you might try.

First, try using valgrind or a similar tool to check for memory leaks. You may have some memory leaks if you don't delete everything you new.

Second, calculate a bound on the number of nodes that should be explored. Keep track of the number of nodes you do explore. If you pass the bound, you might not be detecting cycles properly.

Third, try the algorithm with depth first search instead of A*. Its memory requirements should be linear in the depth of the tree and it should just be a matter of changing the sort ordering (pred). If DFS works, your A* search may be exploring too many nodes or your memory structures might be too inefficient. If DFS doesn't work, again it might be a problem with cycles.

Fourth, try more compact memory structures. For example, std::multiset does what you want but std::priority_queue with a std::deque may take up less memory. There are other changes you could try and see if they improve things.

Comment: Thanks =) the assignment only needs to work for 3x3, and that works just fine in an implementation I did with just lists, so this is just sort-of an assignment question. it does not scale nicely to 4x4 though, hence the attempt at using a hash table. +1 for the helpful suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome. It is often useful to think about how your code scales to bigger problems. Hopefully some of what I suggested you can use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First i would recommend [cantor expansion](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2004/vol5-n1/paper4/v5n1-4pd.pdf), which you can use as the hashing method. It's 1-to-1, i.e. the 16! possible arrangements would be hashed into **0 ~ 16! - 1**.

And then i would implement `map` by my self, as you may know, `std` is not efficient enough for computation. `map` is actually a [`Binary Search Tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), i would recommend `Size Balanced Tree`, or you can use [`AVL tree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

And just for record, directly use `bool hash[]` & `big prime` may also receive good result.

Then the **most important thing** - the `A* function`, like what's in the first of your link, you may try variety of `A* function` and find the best one.

Comment: Your statement about std::map is not generally correct. All std::map implementations that I have seen used red-black trees. Where did you get your library from? It seems to be poorly implemented!

Comment: @kkm i don't think self-implement of some data-structure is poor than `std`, since you know what functions exactly you need, code all the details yourself would be a better choice(only for efficiency). One most widely known issue is that `std::priority_queue` has a bad performance.

Comment: An exercise in implementation of a data structure is unarguably useful, but that is not what really relevant here. My point was that your antecedent is incorrect factually: there are hardly any implementations of `std::map` that are using raw BST.

Comment: Yes and no. It is, just like the AVL tree, binary, and it has specific ordering properties, so it a search tree. So it is a binary search tree, but not the Binary Search Tree. As long as you are opposing BST and AVL, you should be opposing BST and RBT. // By the way, the original idea behind RBT is that of the B-tree, which is a non-binary tree. RBT arose as a binarization of the B-tree with clever "color" marking of nodes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the cantor expansion? I can't figure out what I should use as inputs into the function. {0, 1}, {0, 1, 2} ...{0, ..., 16}

Comment: @aCuria you may like to see this, http://www.nocow.cn/index.php/%E5%BA%B7%E6%89%98%E5%B1%95%E5%BC%80

Answer (score 1):

You are only using the heuristic function to order the multiset. You should use the `min(g(n) + f(n))` i.e. the min(path length + heuristic) to order your frontier.

Here the problem is, you are picking the one with the least heuristic, which may not be the correct "next child" to pick.

I believe this is what is causing your calculation to explode.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the bad naming, manhattan cost has the current cost added to it already.  I should call it total cost or something.

Comment: Ah.. so you are updating the total cost in the node somehow? Because manhattan distance is the property of the Node, but the path cost is dependent on what level you are in the Game tree..

Comment: I have a pointer to parent, and each node knows their own cost.

Comment: I see you havn't gotten a real answer yet. I don't have time right now, but I will try to run your code and see what the problem is.